# NET MAUI8: Tabbed View or Tab control?

Tags: c#, user-interface, maui

I'm creating a `NET8` `MAUI` application to learn this technology better. I have one page where I want to display a list of words and then I have a list of games to play with those words.

The list of words is in the *WordPage* using a `ListView` and the list can be quite long. So, I want to find a nice way to display the list of games. I thought to insert at the end of the page a `CollectionView` with all the games.

[image]

In this case, I found quite uncomfortable to swipe searching for the right button to tap. To arrive at this page, there is a *MainPage* with info about the user and statistics.

The point I want to ask is about creating a `TabbedPage` or some `Tabs` in the *Words* page. The user can go back to the *MainPage* or open another list of words.

I'm asking that because usually I saw apps that implemented the `TabbedPage` but all the content are the tabs of the `TabbedPage`. In my case, I like to user to go back to the *MainPage* or open another page for a game.

I'm not sure about the navigation of this app. At the moment, the flow between pages is based on the `AppShell` navigation.

Comment: One thing to note is that “[TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-8.0) is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use TabbedPage in a Shell app.”